# creating a simple back end design in Laravel for private/public ownership

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, backend

I'm using Laravel for a site where most database objects can be private (i.e., viewed only by their owner) or public (viewed by everyone, including guests). Each of these has a `user_id`, which I set to `NULL` when the object is public.

What's the simplest way of authenticating routes for this scenario? For example, in `/routes/web.php` I have:

```
Route::get('/{tournament}/players', [TournamentController::class, 'indexPlayers']);
```

and I want to make sure that `tournament->user_id` is either `NULL` or corresponds to the user's id. I was able to do this by explicitly binding `tournament` in `/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
Route::bind('tournament', function ($hash) {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id ?? NULL;
    return Tournament::where([['hash', $hash], ['user_id', $user_id]])
        ->orWhere([['hash', $hash], ['user_id', NULL]])
        ->firstOrFail();
});
```

but I have the strong feeling that I'm making it too complicated or doing things in the wrong place. Is there a better way? Should I by doing this inside `TournamentController`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is now the syntax `Auth::id()` that can be used as a shorthand for `Auth::user()->id ?? NULL`, so that saves some trouble.

Next, I ended up moving the logic out of `RouteServiceProvider.php` and into the controller, so that I can explicitly control what happens for public vs. private objects:

```
class TournamentController extends Controller
{
    public function indexPlayers(Tournament $tournament)
    {
        if ($tournament->user_id === NULL) {
            // public
        } else if ($tournament->user_id === Auth::id()) {
            // private
        } else {
            // unauthorized
        }
    }

    ...
}
```